# SQL - Calculate weighted students grades based on grade type

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble calculating student grades based on a specific grade type.

I have the following tables

```
Subject
-------------------
Subid [PK]
subjectTitle

Topic
----------------
Tid (TopicID) [PK]
SubId (Subjectid) [FK]
Designation
WeightOfSubject

Marking
-------------------
pid (PersonID) [PK][FK]
Tid (TopicID) [PK][FK]
Points

Person
------------------------
pid (PersonId) [PK]
firstname
lastname
Sex
```

Paired with the following data.

```
Subject Data

Subid

AA001       Arts
AA002       Crafts


Topic Data

Tid      Subid      Designation WeightOfSubject
001      AA001          S1        30    
002      AA001          S2        30    
003      AA001          S3        40
004      AA002          S1        50
005      AA002          S2        50


Marking DATA

Pid Tid Points(out of 100)
P01 001 33
P01 002 62
P01 003 81
P01 004 85
P01 005 63
P02 001 74
P02 002 72
P02 003 45
P02 004 63
P02 005 88


Person DATA

pid firstname   lastname    sex
P01 Josh        Draxler     M
P02 John        Doe         M
```

What i'd like to do with this is to multply the markings by their weight, and then add all of the weighted scores together to get the average overall weighted for each subject they did (with the final result displaying the subject ids, the person, and their overall weighted average mark as a percentage.)

Although my MYSQL is mediocre at best, I gave it a go, and exprimented with the following (I know its wrong by a mile, dont worry.)

```
SELECT Topic.Designation, Subject.Subid, Subject.subjectTitle, Person.firstname, Person.lastname, AVG(Topic.WeightOfSubject/100*Marking.Points)
FROM Topic, Subject, Person, Marking
WHERE Person.pid = 'P01'
AND Marking.Points = 33
AND Topic.WeightOfSubject = 30
```

Which is fine for just one person, but I'm unsure on how to construct such a query for more than one person, and more than one subject, I've search up JOINS and the such but it really didnt guide me on how I could construct a query for my particular problem. This is the output I would like to expect:

```
Pid  Firstname  Lastname  subjectTitle  Result(WeightedAverage)
001  Josh       Draxler   Arts         (Weighted Average Here)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: share your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I locally (re)created the tables in MySQL 8.0 as shown below:

```
create table subject (
  subid int,
  subjecttitle varchar(10)
);

create table topic (
  tid int,
  subid int,
  designation varchar(10),
  weightofsubject int
);

create table marking (
  pid int,
  tid int,
  points int
);

create table person (
  pid int,
  firstname varchar(20),
  lastname varchar(20),
  sex varchar(1)
);
```

Then, I ran the query shown below. It produces the weighted average for every person and subjects he/she has:

```
select
  p.pid as pid,
  max(p.firstname) as firstname,
  max(p.lastname) as lastname,
  max(p.sex) as sex,
  s.subid, -- you can remove this column, if you wish
  max(s.subjecttitle) as subjecttitle,
  1.0 * sum(m.points * t.weightofsubject) /
    sum(t.weightofsubject) as weighted_average
from subject s
join topic t on t.subid = s.subid
join marking m on m.tid = t.tid
join person p on p.pid = m.pid
group by p.pid, s.subid
order by p.pid, s.subid
```

Comment: Syntax error near 'max(p.firstname) as firstname, max(p.lastname) as lastname, max(p.sex) as sex, s.' ?

Comment: I think it may have been a mismatch in the names of the columns (upper case vs lower case). I added the tables as I tested them locally.